# tee expand new line characters (\n)

Tags: bash

really simple question but I can't seem to Google it. I want to tee a HEREDOC into a file and expand new lines from the variable.

```
user@host:~$ NEWLINEVAR="foo\nbar"
user@host:~$ tee -a > /dev/null filename <<HEREDOC
${NEWLINEVAR}
HEREDOC
```

Current result:

```
user@host:~$ cat filename 
foo\nbar
```

Wanted result:

```
user@host:~$ cat filename 
foo
bar
```

EDIT: I oversimplified my question. Edited above so it's using the HEREDOC implementation I need an answer for.

Comment: `$(printf "$line")` inside the here-doc?

Comment: Thanks @Inian I found the solution in there. I'll mark the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
echo -e ${NEWLINEVAR} | tee -a filename
```

The `-e` option tells `echo` to expand escape sequences.

Comment: Ah I oversimplified the question. I upvoted because you answered what I asked, but I'm actually using HEREDOC. I edited the OP to reflect the situation.